# How to remove email validation magento newsletter registration form to add phone number?

Tags: magento-1.9

How to remove default newsletter registration form email validation magento to add phone number?
In resume, to replace e-mail by phone number.
Magento 1.9.0.0

Thanks!

Comment: You will need email if you're doing "newsletter" registration yes?  Otherwise you need a different form entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this via custom coding.

1. You have to override the `newAction` method of the file `app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php` and remove these line from that method

   ```
   if (!Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress')) {
       Mage::throwException($this->__('Please enter a valid email address.'));
   }
   ```
2. change the html validation here : `app/design/frontend/{namespace}/{theme}/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml`

Change input type from **`email` to `text`** from field `email`

Remove class **`validate-email`**  from field `email`

Comment: unfortunately still with the same problem
this authenticating email
See the files changed on the link in the link.

https://www.fotobolo.com.br/hometeste5

 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1Z21NKicYb-YjFxSXNWOHFqTWc?usp=sharing